# How to diagnose computer fan refusing to spin?

Tags: hardware-failure, diagnostic

I've got a ARCTIC Freezer 7 Pro Rev 2 and after it was through the luggage of an Australia > Europe flight, sometimes it refuses to work and stops spinning. I'm not able to figure out why. How can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: is it plugged in?

Comment: Yep - I don't touch the hardware between the times it decides to spin or not.

Comment: -1   the subject of your question is so badly written that the obvious answer is you look at it and see that it is not spinning and hey presto you diagnosed that it is not spinning. The other question is what to do about it (which your subject doesn't ask)

Comment: I don't think you know what 'diagnose' means. Diagnose does not mean observe. It means find out _why_.

Comment: @Vadi The "why" is obvious the hardware is damaged.  You don't repair hardware like a heat sink fan.  The costs to do so are just to high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's damaged and needs to be replaced. It possibly got squashed, or lubrication did not like the low pressure of the cargo hold or whatever and now the fan has a higher resistance meaning it needs more current to start.

That said, it's conceivable (but unlikely) your new environment is simply cooler and the fan does not need to run as much. Get some CPU monitoring software and monitor the CPU temp. Also get something (like prime95) to stress test CPU and see if the fan kicks in to FL gear - good - or if it starts to reduce CPU speed - bad, it's throttling because it's to hot.

Comment: The temperature is through the roof and my OS is clamping the CPU to keep the hardware from shutting itself off.

Guess I'll have to look at replacing it, yeah.

Comment: @mayrrdesign. Yup - we wrote our answers at the same time. Only saw yours when I pressed submit.

Answer (score 3):

If it only stops sometimes and your environment is cool, then the heat-sink on such a large cooler might be doing an adequate job of cooling the CPU by itself.

Monitor the CPU temperature to find out.

In fact you mention moving from Australia (I assume hot) to Europe which makes me even more suspicious that this could be the cause.

Comment: hmm. Some motherboards have a set of temperature profiles they use to turn the fans off and on. Good catch.

Comment: The temperature is through the roof and my OS is clamping the CPU to keep the hardware from shutting itself off.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Thanks very much. In fact this happened to me some years back, but the opposite way around. A quiet computer turned noisier when I moved to Spain haha (from the UK)

Comment: @Vadi, In that case I am certainly wrong then! :( Of course the most likely explanation here is physical damage and you should replace the cooler unit.